# var_dump() of strings and variables not showing desired results

Tags: php, arrays, string, var-dump

I am working on a script that curls another site and then parses the results. I seem to be having some weird problems and I can't understand where they are coming from; I have included the problematic part of my code as well as the output that is returned from it below:

```
<?php
    //my code to do some logic and build the curl

    $BookingConfirmation = curl_exec($ch);

    $testString = 'a test';
    var_dump($testString);
    echo '<br />';
    echo $BookingConfirmation;
    echo '<br />';
    var_dump($BookingConfirmation);
    echo '<br />';

    $bookingResults = explode('|', $BookingConfirmation);

    var_dump($bookingResults);
    die();
?>
```

when I then load the page, I am getting this output:

```
string(6) "a test"
booking|1||4000015|23628
string(2386) " booking|1||4000015|23628 "
array(6) { 
    [0]=> string(766) " string(1526) "108^1"> booking" 
    [2]=> string(1) "1" 
    [3]=>     string(0) "" 
    [4]=> string(7) "4000015" 
    [5]=> string(81) "23628 " 
}
```

So according to what $BookingConfirmation is showing me, I wouldn't expect the array to contain "108^1" anywhere within it. Also, why would the var_dump of $BookingConfirmation be showing that it is a 2386 character string? It is nowhere near that long. Another question is, what is happening with the second element that should be in the array? ($bookingResults[1]) The final dump of that array is showing that there are 6 elements, but with #1 being skipped there are only 5 being shown.

It also might be useful to note that none of these variable names are used anywhere else in the code.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, `string(2386) " booking|1||4000015|23628 "`, That means the string has `2386` bytes. You should look the `view-source` of your test page, instead of the rendered html which is obviously hiding most of the string.

Comment: @Esailija maybe xdebug settings?  Does standard php.ini let you control the behavior of var_dump at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either use view-source, text/plain content-type, or run it through command line.

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");
    //my code to do some logic and build the curl

    $BookingConfirmation = curl_exec($ch);

    $testString = 'a test';
    var_dump($testString);
    echo '<br />';
    echo $BookingConfirmation;
    echo '<br />';
    var_dump($BookingConfirmation);
    echo '<br />';

    $bookingResults = explode('|', $BookingConfirmation);

    var_dump($bookingResults);
    die();
?>
```

I suspect the input contained `<`, which is rendered as some hidden html tag. I mean,`string(2386) " booking|1||4000015|23628 "`, means the string has `2386` bytes.

Comment: ya that worked perfect thanks; turns out there was a hidden input element and one of the values had a pipe (|) in it that was being caught on the explode

Comment: Thank you. How should the < tag be escaped

Answer (score 1):

To see the result of the function `var_dump()` literally, use [HTML's pre element](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp):

```
  echo '<pre>';
  var_dump( $bookingResults );  
  echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

use `print_r()` with pre tags instead of `var_dump()`

```
echo '<pre>';
  print_r( $bookingResults );  
echo '</pre>';
```

Hope it helps